# Cannot resolve Symbol R, where is gen folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have created a dummy Android project from within Android studio, and I can make it run, but the Editor itself fails to find the R class. In fact I can't find the gen folder. I thought that maybe that folder should be added as a source folder or a classes dependency, but I just can't find it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@joe_deniable gave me the idea to look closer in the build folder, and I found a folder that had been *excluded* by intellij, where my R was happily having an ice cream. This was here:

build/source/aidl/debug

I had to remove this folder from the exclusion list and add it to the sources, and could finally start coding in this new IDE.

Thanks

Comment: How do you find the exclusion list?

Comment: In the module confiuration, Sources tab, you will see some project folders are included in the source path, and some are excluded.

Answer (score 4):

The folder layout is different to eclipse. I don't think there's a "gen" folder. My "R" file is in the following location:

(module name)/build/source/r/debug/(package name)/R.java

I think this file is created when you create a new project using the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on linux. I've resolved it installing ia32libs and rebuilding the project. The R class is generated from android.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it in the directory app/build/generated/source/r/debug/package name.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the package you used has some issue - the target package is not the same with the defined one. In turn, R can not be found in the package.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Goto to Top right corner in Studio, click on search button enter R.java , you will get the file

thank you