# How do i solve the issue of missing R class?

Tags: android

I downloaded android studio about two weeks ago and I have built and tested about three projects on it and it worked fine. I tried creating a new project some days ago and it gave an Error

> ("Could not resolve the symbol R")

...tried rebuilding project, restarted android studio , clean project ...nothing worked. I checked where the R file is meant to be, I have nothing like it there. Please , how do resolve this?

Comment: I don't have access to Android Studio right now, so I cannot try this but it may work for you. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-cannot-resolve-symbol-r-in-android-studio

Comment: could you upload your manifest and layout xml files?

Comment: In the future, copying and pasting your error message exactly will both help you find existing answers and help future Googlers who have the same problem find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right import.

Example:

```
import com.my.app.R;
```

Alternatively, you can press `Alt + Enter` (Windows) or `Control + Enter` (Mac) to have Android Studio suggest imports for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the relevant layout.
Just place the cursor near **R** and press **Alt + Enter**.

Most probably this will automatically import the layouts. Else you have to import them manually.

Comment: I have tried Alt+Enter before now...The issue is that I don't think the R class is there at all.So,there really is nothing to import.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623830/cannot-resolve-symbol-r-where-is-gen-folder-in-android-studio

Answer (score -1):

> Goto File -> Settings -> Compiler now check use external build
>   then rebuild project